# Pushbutton Noisy Signal

Tags: resistors, switches, gpio-external-interrupt

I have a pushbutton setup and occasionally it is randomly triggered without someone pressing it. Would this be because I have a larger resistor on the 3.3V GPIO (reads the input and possibly susceptible to being a noisy GPIO pin)?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNaW6O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What's your reason for having R2?

Comment: Are you saying that the GPIO reads a 1 when no one is pressing the switch, or are you talking about switch bounce? The above looks fine to me.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, the GPIO will occasionally read a 1 on its own. The bounce is set to 50 seconds so plenty of time for user to only produce 1 event.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a problem with your switch, and are you sure the pin is set as in input?

Comment: @copper.hat How would I verify the issue is not the switch? Yes the GPIO is set as an input and also the pull-down is set.

Comment: Have you tried changing the switch button?

Comment: I have used different ones but i'ts not easy to recreate the issue. It is random but the circuits are all built the same

Comment: Can you disconnect the switch? What do you mean by the pull down is set? It should be high impedance; the resistors above will do the pull down.

Comment: How long are the wires to the switch? Is R2 close to the MCU or the switch?

Comment: Is it always random on the same button or random over random buttons?

Comment: It is random over random buttons. Highly unpredictable behavior.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany R2 is close to the switch and the wires are less than 4 inches long

Comment: @copper.hat The components are all soldered together. There is a SW pull-down that I set as well.

Comment: Why set the pulldown?

Comment: Is it possible you have a firmware problem, or there is some reset of the MCU occurring?

Comment: Your interface look fine, I think something else is going on.

Comment: get rid of the resistors ... enable the internal pullup resistor ... connect the switch between the GPIO pin and ground

Answer (score 1):

Pushbuttons are susceptible to ['bouncing'](https://people.cs.clemson.edu/%7Eyfeaste/855Assignments/presentations/team6-button-bounce.pdf) and can generally be dealt with using software. [This](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/debounce) example from Arduino illustrates a possible way to implement a delay to prevent bouncing. The wiring looks good though!

Comment: I have a 50 second bouncetime set. This button press occurs when no one is around the circuit. What could cause this noise? 

Also, is the 12k resistor serving any purpose?  I thought it was needed but now it logically doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have some idea what it could be. First of all, are you confident in your circuit? I'm not sure how it works. So default unpressed state is 0V pulled down by 2.2k? And then 3.3V comes and triggers it, right? Because this does look a little strange.

Things to look at: your 12k resistor. Please, take a look what impedance your GPIO pin has when it's input. If it's of the range of 100k+, you don't have to worry much, but if it's, say, 20k or 50k, then a resistor inside your gpio pin make a divider with 12k resistor and you can expect a result which you can't expect - if that voltage divider is around threshold for detecting press, you can get erratic behavior.

You could actually switch the 12k and 2.2k around and add a little debouncing cap, thus removing need for software debounce. 2.2k would probably still work. Try it.

But personally, I would replace 12k resistor with 100 Ohm - 1kOhm resistor, and I would place a small debouncing cap between GPIO and this 100R resistor (1uF for example). And 2k2->12k since you have that resistor (or leave 2k2 there, it just wastes current). Don't put higher impedance resistors in series with MCU inputs unless there's a specific reason why no other design would work there.